# Adding json data to selectfield in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I am having some issues getting the values to actually load in a Sencha Touch selectfield when I try to load a json file.

The relevant pieces of my code are:

```
  Ext.regModel('d', {
fields: [{ 
            name: 'Name', type: 'string'
        }, { 
            name: 'id', type: 'int'
        }]
});

Ext.regStore('TempStore', {
    model: 'd',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/sampledata.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'd'
        }
    }
});

items: [{
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            label:'My Field',
            id: 'Test',
            name: 'Name',
            store: 'TempStore',
            displayField: 'Name',
            valueField: 'id',
            placeHolder: 'Select a Value'
        }
```

I have the samepledata.json file in the same folder as the .js file, and the page loads fine but when I press the selectfield it comes with an empty list.

Any ideas?

EDIT: typos

Answer (score 0):

Please remove quotes around the store name.

```
items: [{
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            label:'My Field',
            id: 'Test',
            name: 'Name',
            store: TempStore, //No quotes here.
            displayField: 'Name',
            valueField: 'id',
            placeHolder: 'Select a Value'
        }
```

Also see: [Sencha Touch SelectField API](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Select)

Comment: instead of Ext.regstore try var TempStore= new Ext.data.Store({ model: 'd', autoLoad: true, proxy:.....});

Comment: hmm, still not working. (for live example you can check out http://selectout.net/oil/app/ then click add data on the left, then trailer setup on the top. this will bring you to the page that has the field).

thanks for the help though, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do this:

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    label: 'Cuenta',
    name: 'cuenta',
    store: 'TipoPago',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
}
```

And it works perfectly. Of course I have my model and store already defined for `TipoPago`, I have `myapp.store.TipoPago` and `myapp.model.TipoPago`.